# lldb cannot connect to debugserver using python API

Tags: remote-debugging, lldb

I'm trying to connect to debugserver on Mac, using lldb. While the following set of commands work fine and in the lldb cli, the same set of commands fails with `error: the platform is not currently connected` when run from python using the `debugger.GetCommandInterpreter().HandleCommand`.

I also tried using the direct Python APIs without much luck. Though, I'm interested to learn more about the difference and making it work with interpreter in python.enter code here

For more context: https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/issues/411

Start debug server:

```
$ lldb/bin/debugserver 127.0.0.1:1234
...
```

lldb CLI (works):

```
(lldb) platform select remote-macosx
(lldb) target create ~/Projects/vscode-lldb/build/debuggee/debuggee
(lldb) process connect connect://127.0.0.1:1234
(lldb) process launch 
Process 64302 launched: '/Users/nisarg/Projects/vscode-lldb/build/debuggee/debuggee' (x86_64)
...
```

Python (error: the platform is not currently connected):

```
>>> import sys; sys.path.append('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python3')
>>> from lldb import *
>>> debugger = SBDebugger.Create()
>>> inter = debugger.GetCommandInterpreter()
>>> res = SBCommandReturnObject()
>>> commands = ['platform select remote-macosx', 'target create /Users/nisarg/Projects/vscode-lldb/build/debuggee/debuggee', 'process connect connect://127.0.0.1:1234', 'process launch']
>>> for command in commands: inter.HandleCommand(command, res); print(command); print(res.Succeeded()); print(res.GetOutput(), "\n", res.GetError())
... 
2
platform select remote-macosx
True
  Platform: remote-macosx
 Connected: no
 
 
1
target create /Users/nisarg/Projects/vscode-lldb/build/debuggee/debuggee
True
Current executable set to '/Users/nisarg/Projects/vscode-lldb/build/debuggee/debuggee' (x86_64).
 
 
1
process connect connect://127.0.0.1:1234
True
 
 
There is a running process, kill it and restart?: [Y/n] y
6
process launch
False
 
 error: the platform is not currently connected
```

The same behaviour is observed when trying to connect to debugserver running locally on Mac or forwarded debugserver from iOS.

Comment: How are you launching debugserver?  If you give debugserver a path to the executable when you launch it, it will launch that process and stop it at its entry point waiting for an attach.  But debugserver only debugs one process and then exits, so if you attach to debugserver at that point, and then say "kill the current process" debugserver will exit as well.  I'm guessing that is what is happening in your Python example, and maybe you are launching debugserver differently in the command line case?

Comment: If you want to have lldb in charge of launching the process, just launch debugserver with the connect port and that's all.  Then when lldb attaches, it will send debugserver the commands to do the launch.  If you want to start up debugserver with a process already - as above - then on attach you should continue the process rather than launching it.

Comment: I'm launching debugserver the same way using `lldb/bin/debugserver 127.0.0.1:1234` as mentioned in the question. If I give an executable path to debugserver while launching, and attach using lldb, it works fine on attaching, but I would want to just start debugserver and launch from within lldb.

Comment: I'm launching debugserver the same way on both the cases, and running the same commands via lldb cli, or python debugger.interpreter, but getting different results in both the cases.